# Looking for geodata of Europe's major roads

Tags: openstreetmap, data, europe

As stated in the title, I'm currently looking for a shapefile/other geodata source of Europe's major roads (highways). If anybody knows a free datasource (or a possibility to extract that data from Open Street Map without processing the world file), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thought I'd share what I found through lengthy research. It seems, the UNECE (United Nations Economic Commission for Europe) has conducted a transportation network census in 2005. Hidden deep inside their Website, I have found this:

http://www.unece.org/transport/areas-of-work/transport-statistics/statistics-and-data-online/e-roads/transmainwp6e-roads-census-2005.html

You have to download the ArcReader-project, which, when unzipped, contains routable, simplified shapefiles of all major roads along with some useful metadata. Same applies to the train network which can also be found on the page.

[image]

Comment: The projection information seems to be missing from the first archive at that link. It's a polyconic projection using the Clarke 1866 ellipsoid, the `proj4` string for the projection is `+proj=poly +lat_0=33 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=-2222408.5 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs`.

Comment: The choice of the second archive ("Roads ArcReader Projects") with the projection information included is working well.

Answer (score 7):

You can download nightly OpenStreetMap Europe snapshots from here:

http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/

As of today:

- europe.osm.bz2    03-May-2012 06:31   11G OpenStreetMap data, bzip2 compressed
- europe.osm.pbf    03-May-2012 00:56   7.8G    OpenStreetMap data, protobuf binary format

Using GDAL/OGR you can then extract the roads with a SQL statement (see https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html) by querying e.g. the type.

Comment: Thanks, but the amount of time and work needed to process this huge file is too high. I need a really abstracted dataset, such as shown here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_E-road_network

Comment: Last link is dead.

Comment: New link: https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html

Answer (score 5):

For this, EuroGeographic (one of the official European GIS data provider) released as an opendata product [the EuroGlobalMap dataset](http://www.eurogeographics.org/products-and-services/euroglobalmap)

Data contrary to the link info about "Delivery formats available" can be directly downloaded as SHP (not "on demand")

The dataset contains six themes:

- Administrative boundaries
- The water network
- **Transport networks**
- Settlements
- Elevation
- Names locations

Another dataset can be the Global Roads Open Access Data Set (gROADS), v1 (1980 – 2010). Look into it at the [Columbia University website](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/groads-global-roads-open-access-v1/data-download)

Answer (score 3):

Following from markusN, there are OpenStreetmap downloads at GeoFabrik that are in shapefile format and therefore don't require processing (depending on the dataset).

Alternately, there's one here:
http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-europe-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm

But at 900MB, I suspect its not abstracted.

Comment: Great - thanks for the link! That seems to be excactly what i was looking for.